# Top 20 vba, large returning double, instead of decimal

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to retrieve the top 20 values from an array of thousands of lines. However, the worksheet function large is retrieving a double rather than the decimal, in other words, the search item is coming back with 2.1110000, even though the value should be 0.0021110000. This is a huge problem because then when I search I am not finding the values.

Ideally, the code would identify the top 20 values in an array and retrieve some values from the columns at the same row number as the top 20 values.

```
Sub top20()
Dim c
    bk.Range("A18") = "Top20": bk.Range("A19") = "CNumber": bk.Range("B19") = "IT": bk.Range("C19") = "SN": bk.Range("D19") = "C": bk.Range("E19") = "P"
    For i = 1 To 20
        fltArr = wrk.Range("AL2:AL" & wrk.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
        With wrk.Range("AL:AL")
            searchitem = (WorksheetFunction.Large(Arg1:=fltArr, Arg2:=i))
            Set c = .Find(searchitem)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                bk.Range("A20").Offset(i, 0) = wrk.Range("B" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A20").Offset(i, 1) = wrk.Range("F" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A20").Offset(i, 2) = wrk.Range("G" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A20").Offset(i, 3) = wrk.Range("H" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A20").Offset(i, 4) = wrk.Range("J" & c.Row)
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    bk.Range("A16") = "Top20p": bk.Range("A27") = "CN": bk.Range("B27") = "IT": bk.Range("C27") = "SN": bk.Range("D27") = "C": bk.Range("E27") = "P"

    For i = 1 To 20
        With wrk.Range("AM:AM")
            Set c = .Find(WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.Large(bk.Range("AL:AL"), (i))))
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                bk.Range("A27").Offset(i, 0) = wrk.Range("B" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A27").Offset(i, 1) = wrk.Range("F" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A27").Offset(i, 2) = wrk.Range("G" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A27").Offset(i, 3) = wrk.Range("H" & c.Row)
                bk.Range("A27").Offset(i, 4) = wrk.Range("J" & c.Row)
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: can I see a screenshot of the worksheet that you're working with?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is at work and the information is locked down. Ultimately, after the find c is 2.1110000 when it should be 0.0021110000.

Comment: That doesn't seems like it's working at all - I don't see how the difference between Double and Decimal could account for what you're seeing.  Try specifying all of the arguments to Find(), or at least `LookAt` and `LookIn`

Comment: Dumb question... could you just divide by 1,000 and get what you want?

Comment: @CRUTER indeed, I was thinking of checking how many zeros there were after the dot and then dividing by the appropriate value.

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams, I can't see how double vs decimal explains your difference.

Comment: I would advise against dividing anything - there is something wrong in your code and that's not going to fix it.

Comment: @TimWilliams because the value is stored in searchitem I can clearly see the value is incorrect, moreover, it does not find the value when it searches. In terms of the problem, a double 2.1, is different from 0.0021, as a result of the dot, it is not finding the value when it searches.

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense to me.  It would help to update your question with a set of numbers you're using Large() against: in my testing there was no problem at all.

Comment: @TimWilliams again it is hard to show values, the numbers are really small because they are a percentage of a larger value - value/total amount of values in the column.

Comment: As @TimWilliams noted above, you likely need to specify `LookIn` arg of `Find`. When you use the `Large` function that will examine cells by Value. `LookIn` is volative --- it starts off examining Formulas, but will retain whatever setting was used in the last `Find`. Searching Formulas will probably fail when looking for a Value.

Comment: *Ultimately, after the find c is 2.1110000 when it should be 0.0021110000* - are you sure it's not `2.111e-3`? (didn't read all that code, just the comments)

Comment: It's not hard to show numbers - just add them to your question, or share a workbook with a single column of values: the rest of the data is irrelevant.